# How to delete information between [ ] and keep any text after it

Tags: google-bigquery

If I have text such as:
[12 Dec 2012 20:12:12 GMT] The Weather was amazing in Cyprus.

Using Google BigQuery I would like to keep "The Weather was amazing in Cyprus." but remove the bracket how can I do this.

I am new to this.

I tried REGEXP_EXTRACT but struggling. PLEASE HELP
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also this using REGEX_EXTRACT approach. See query below where the regex `(.+)` enclosed in parenthesis `'r^\[.+\](.+)'` represents any value after the brackets will be extracted:

```
with sample_data as (
    select '[12 Dec 2012 20:12:12 GMT] The Weather was amazing in Cyprus.' as test_string
)
select test_string 
    , regexp_extract(test_string, r'^\[.+\](.+)') as result_extract
from sample_data
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the below utilizing the REGEXP_REPLACE function:

```
with sample_data as (
    select '[12 Dec 2012 20:12:12 GMT] The Weather was amazing in Cyprus.' as test_string
)
select test_string 
    , regexp_replace(test_string , r'\[.+]\s', '') as result
from sample_data
```